# Ollydbg problem

Tags: ollydbg, kernel-mode

When I run Ollydbg in my Windows7 (x32) using kernel mode in StrongOd Plugin it doesn't load correctly and log shows this error:

```
Log data, item 0 Message=StartService Failed, err = 2
```

And when loading any program it terminates itself. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

StrongOD is not recommendable on Windows 7 environment, If you are on Windows 7 is better to go with:

- ScyllaHide v0.7 https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3560
- TitanHide (TitanEngine): https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/34431-titanhide/

Hope this works for you!

Cheers~!

Answer (score 0):

Run as admin? Try running procmon or api monitor to see what calls are failing if that's not the reason.

Comment: But yeah StartService is an SCM call, either the service isn't valid or you don't have the privs to start it.